# An infinite context free language can be split into two infinite regular languages

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar

Prove or disprove

Let $L$ be an infinite context free language. Show that there exists a regular language $R$ such that $ L \cap R $ and $L \cap \overline{R} $ are infinite and regular.

Comment: Where did you get this question from?  As sdcvvc points out, it's never true unless $L$ itself is regular.

Answer (score 3):

As stated, this cannot be true. If $L \cap R$ and $L \cap \overline{R}$ are regular, then $L$ also must be regular as a sum of regular languages.

Here is a hint to show existence of $R$ such that $L \cap R$ and $L \cap \overline{R}$ are infinite. First, solve the problem when the alphabet is unary. You might use the fact that context-free languages for unary alphabets are regular. How does an infinite regular language for unary alphabet look like? For general alphabets, think about reduction to unary case (by substituting all letters to a single fixed one).

Comment: I'm not so sure on the first assertion, $(L \cap R) \cup (L \cap \overline{R}) \ne L$

Comment: @vonbrand: Every word in $L$ is either in $R$ or in $\overline{R}$, so it's in $L \cap R$ or $L \cap \overline{R}$.

Comment: Right, brain malfunction. :-(

Comment: In my defense, I'd suggest looking at [Parikh's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parikh%27s_theorem) for inspiration on a way of building such an $R$.